# Subclassed QSpinBox does not take valueFromText

Tags: c++, qt

I subclassed a `QSpinBox` (or rather a `SpinBox`, which inherits `QSpinBox`), sticking to [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1405227). This SpinBox is displaying hexadecimal values. Displaying and in- decrementing via buttons works fine, but it does not take any entered values (jumps back to previous value). I cant find a hint for that behaviour in the reference for any of the overriden functions: [`validate(QString &, int &) const : QValidator::State`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractspinbox.html#validate), [`valueFromText(const QString &) const : int`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qspinbox.html#valueFromText) and [`textFromValue(int) const : QString`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qspinbox.html#textFromValue)

Here is my implementation:

```
#include "hexspinbox.h"

#include <QtGui>
#include <QRegExp>
#include <QRegExpValidator>

HexSpinBox::HexSpinBox(const QString& define, const QString& header, const QPoint& topLeft, const QSize& size, const QString& defaultValue, const QPoint& range, QWidget* parent)
    : SpinBox(define, header, topLeft, size, defaultValue, range, parent)
{
    if (!size.isEmpty())
        setFixedSize(size);
    if (!topLeft.isNull())
        move(topLeft);
    if (!range.isNull())
        setRange(range.x(), range.y());
    validator = new QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("[0-9A-Fa-f]{1-8}"), this);
    setPrefix("0x");
    init();
}

QValidator::State HexSpinBox::validate(QString& text, int& pos) const
{
    return validator->validate(text, pos);
}

QString HexSpinBox::textFromValue(int value) const
{
    return QString::number(value, 16).toUpper();
}

int HexSpinBox::valueFromText(const QString& text) const
{
    bool ok;
    return text.toInt(&ok, 16);
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `text` in `validate(QString, int)` after inserting?

Comment: In validate the any string will be printed but only values from 0 - F will be displayed. Twice, whysoever, but the value will be the previous (any value entered by clicking) value.

Comment: No, I mean, what does the debugger give as value for `text` and what state is returned from `validator->validate(text, pos);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`validator = new QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("[0-9A-Fa-f]{1-8}"), this);`

Should be

`validator = new QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("0x[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,8}"), this);`

Notice the `0x` and the `,` instead of `-`. `text` Includes the prefix, but your pattern does not. Afterwards it was easy to notice that you made a typo in your regex range.